# Flash Builder 4.6 How to get the session id of the user?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, blazeds, flash-builder4.5

I'm using Java + BlazeDS4 + Tomcat + FlashBuilder4.6

....

How do I get the session id for each user logged into the site?

I would like to get the session id and closes her case is connected in several places with the same user.

...

I searched all over the internet and found nothing related to this.

I'm new in Flash Builder and thank all the help.

thank you

Comment: Does Flash Builder have server side components, and in that case using what framework? Only the server knows about all connections, so a client can't really make that call.

Comment: I don't understand what sessionID you are referring to!  Are you talking about a Flex/flash Application built with Flash Builder?  Or are you explicitly trying to do some Flash Builder Plugin development?  Are you referring to a unique ID assigned to a server side session?  Or something different?

Comment: Joachim Isaksson, I'm using Java + BlazeDS, any idea how to do this?

Comment: Reboog, I'm using Java + BlazeDS + Tomcat + FlashBuilder is a normal application made ​​in Flash Builder, just precison of sessionID, I think I can get by BlazeDS not understand how to do this.

Comment: @user2530802 Then, if I understand, you need to get the Java-session from inside your Flash App?  Usually browser cookies are used to maintain the session on the server side between multiple requests from the client. And Flash Player will send those browser cookies with each request so, in theory your backend service should have access to session variables for the user who logged into the Flash app.  Were you having a specific problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, if you are using adapters or the servlets to find out, you may want to maintain the map of the username=UserSessionID.

To get the usersession id, get you can use FlexContext.getFlexSession() or you can use FlexSession.getServletRequest().getSession()

More no this [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/javadoc/flex/messaging/FlexContext.html)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, I also found the link below which helped me a lot.  
link: http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=lcconnections_3.html